# Modal Popup on Dynamic Button

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender, dynamic-controls

In my Web application, I am dynamically adding a Button named as "Click Me !". At Stage 1 , when the Button is clicked, it has to show a alert box . At Stage 2, it has to show a Popup.
I use ModalPopupExtender to achieve popup. The Problem is, the popup is just blinked once, instead of Displaying it constantly. Given below my codes...can any one help me to get rid of this ?

```
Page_OnLoad():
**************
     Button Button1=new Button();
     Button1.Text="Click Me !";
     Button1.ID="LogBut";
     Controls.Add(LogBut);
```

Stage 1:

```
      JavaScript:
      ***********
          function alert()
          {
             alert("Stage 1");
          }

      Code behind:
      ************
       LogBut.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "alert();");
```

Stage 2:

```
      JavaScript:
      ***********
          var Modalpopup='<%=modalPermission.ClientID %>';
          function Popup()
          {
             $find(Modalpopup).show();
          }

     Design:
     *******
           <Ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPermission" runat="server" TargetControlID="Infield"
                   PopupControlID="divPermission"></Ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="Infield" runat="server" />

     Code Behind:
     ************
           LogBut.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "Popup();");
```

Note: I am using the hidden field control's Id as ModaPopupExtender's TargetControlId.  Am adding this button inside calendar control.

Screenshots of the calendar:

[image: Design Page]
[image: Code Behind]

Answer (score 1):

Modal popups do not remember that it's supposed to show after a popup.  If you are attaching a popup show to a button, you have to disable the postback to the server.  Most likely your problem is the button shows the modal, but also posts back, and on postback, the modal doesn't remember it's supposed to show.  You can kill the postback by doing the following; set

```
UseSubmitBehavior='false'
```

on the server-side button, and then in the Popup function, do:

```
function Popup(e) {
   // stop button event propagation, which causes postback
   if (e.stopPropagation)
      e.stopPropagation();
   if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();

   // show modal
}
```

And that should prevent a button postback to the server.

EDIT: Your function said Popup, but your javascript is rendering showpopup() as the function call.  If that function doesn't exist (and spelled the exact same), it will never stop the postback.

Comment: Its working for me. But the thing is when I am adding that button inside a Calendar control, Its not working.

Comment: Sorry @Brian Mains, instead of editing my post. I Edited your comment. Really Sorry.

Comment: Not a problem.  I fixed it.  Also edited my post... the method on the server is showpopup(), your code sample has Popup().  They have to have the same name.

Comment: Just change the function name to Popup() on the server-side for your OnClick attribute.

Comment: Ya... the function name is changed to showpopup(), in code behind. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Yeah @Brian Mains...Changed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33979/discussion-between-ognale88-and-brian-mains)